# Ember Template Compiler

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to `ember.js` and javascript frontend MVCs.

I am running into:

`Cannot call 'compile' without the template compiler loaded`
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10265

So I added:

```
app.import('bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js');
```

to the top level of my project directory in the `Brocfile.js`.

```
ember build
Future versions of Ember CLI will not support v0.10.33. Please update to Node 0.12 or io.js.
version: 0.2.5

A new version of ember-cli is available (0.2.6). To install it, type ember update.
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://www.ember-cli.com/#watchman for more info.
Building..
controllers/application.js: line 1, col 16, 'Ember' is not defined.

1 error

===== 1 JSHint Error

Warning: ignoring input sourcemap for bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js because ENOENT, no such file or directory 'proj/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-HJiSoIdK.tmp/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.map'
```

Is there a separate build step that I am missing to create the template compiler map as the last warning fails create the necessary source map?

Comment: What version of ember are you using?

Comment: the template-compiler is just a warning, but your error is that in controllers/application you forgot to import ember. (I don't know about the template compiler, just pointing out this error).

Comment: there is a much newer version of Ember cli out (1.13.7+), if you are still new to Ember I would recommend switching to the latest of everything (and upgrading your node version as well.)

Comment: With the latest Ember CLI (1.13.12), you still get the sourcemap warning for ember-template-compiler. I'm thinking it's safe to ignore.