# Ember Cli 0.2.7 initializers Loader Uncaught Error: Could not find module

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Hi I have recently upgraded to the latest version of Ember-Cli and encountered an issue where if I attempt to load the page (by going to the url after typing the command `ember server` ) it doesnt load the page an give the error:

Uncaught Error: Could not find module `torii/redirect-handler` imported from `ui/initializers/initialize-torii-callback`

If I remove the tori configuration from the environment.js. This error does not occur.

Has somethings changed in ember cli where i must explicitly define initializers instead of configuring them in environment.js file ?

I have provided a partial bower/package.json and environment.js to illustrate the point

```
$ ember version
version: 0.2.7
node: 0.12.6
npm: 2.11.0
```

Bower.json

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.12.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.18",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.4",
    "ember-qunit": "0.3.3",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.15",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.0",
    "qunit": "~1.17.1",
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for ui goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.12",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.2",
    "broccoli-funnel": "^0.2.3",
    "broccoli-merge-trees": "^0.2.1",
    "ember-cli": "0.2.7",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "0.3.3",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-cookie": "^0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "0.7.6",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-less": "^1.1.1",
    "ember-cli-pusher": "0.1.2",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.13",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth": "^0.7.3",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth-oauth2": "^0.7.2",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth-torii": "^0.8.0-beta.1",
    "ember-cli-tooltipster": "0.0.6",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.18",
    "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-idx-button": "^0.1.3",
    "ember-idx-forms": "^0.5.1",
    "ember-mousetrap": "0.2.0",
    "ember-template-compiler": "^1.9.0-alpha",
    "express": "^4.8.5",
    "glob": "^4.0.5",
    "torii": "^0.3.3"
  }
}
```

environment.js

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
 torii: {
      providers: {
        'facebook-connect': {
          appId: '**********',
          scope: 'public_profile,email,user_friends'
        },
    },
```

Comment: Seems like its a bug with the current version of ember-cli: https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/264

Comment: Have you tried with the lastest version 1.13.1?

Comment: When I attempt to use it there are a bunch of errors which occurs. There are significant changes to ember 1.13 hence I rather not use it. Interestingly enough there have been some changes to the instance initializers which might be causing this issue to occur in ember 1.12 http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/13/ember-1-12-released.html